# Java immutable-class rules

Tags: java, immutability

Is the below class immutable:

```
final class MyClass {
    private final int[] array;
    public MyClass(int[] array){
        this.array = array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No it is not because the elements of the array can still be changed.

```
int[] v1 = new int[10];
MyClass v2 = new MyClass(v1);
v1[0] = 42;  // mutation visible to MyClass1
```

Comment: Ah right! I keep forgetting that the reference is assigned to the private member.

Comment: @Chaos: It couldn't be a wrapper. It would have to take a copy of the passed in array. It can't wrap anything that the original caller could still mutate.

Comment: @Jon - A simple semantic faux pas is all. My mistake was in thinking that a copy was implied.

Comment: You have to keep all references to that array internal.  You could allow retrieving of individual elements without returning the entire array or you could program using OO methodologies by placing code that needs to access the array inside this class itself, making it both immutable AND OO.

Comment: So is this immutable?

final class MyClass {
    private final int[] array;
    public MyClass(int[] array){
        this.array = array.clone();
    }
}

Answer (score 6):

My two cents regarding immutability rules (which I retained from reading Effective Java - a great book!):

1. Don't provide methods that can modify the state of an object.
2. Make all your fields final.
3. Make sure that your class is non-extendable.
4. Make all your fields private.
5. Provide exclusive access to any fields or components of your class that *can* be changed. Essentially this applies to your situation (as [explained by JaredPar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142817/java-immutable-class-rules/3142824#3142824)). A person that uses your class still has a reference to your array. The opposite is the case where you return *a reference* to an component of your class. In this case, always create *defensive copies*. In your case, you should not assign the reference. Instead, copy the array that the user of your class provides, into your internal component.

Comment: And don't implement `Serializable`.

Answer (score 1):

"Immutability" is a convention between the programmer and himself. That convention may be more or less enforced by the compiler.

Instances of a class are "immutable" if they do not change during the normal course of the application code execution. In some cases we *know* that they do not change because the code actually forbids it; in other cases, this is just part of how we use the class. For instance, a `java.util.Date` instance is formally mutable (there is a `setTime()` method on it) but it is customary to handle it as if it were immutable; this is just an application-wide convention that the `Date.setTime()` method shall not be called.

As additional notes:

- Immutability is often thought of in terms of "external characteristics". For instance, Java's `String` is documented to be immutable (that's what the Javadoc says). But if you look at the source code, you will see that a `String` instance contains a private field called `hash` which may change over time: this is a cache for the value returned by `hashCode()`. We still say that `String` is immutable because the `hash` field is an internal optimization which has no effect visible from the outside.
- With reflection, the most private of instance fields can be modified (including those marked as `final`), if the programmer wishes so hard enough. Not that it is a good idea: it may break assumptions used by other pieces of code using the said instance. As I said, immutability is a convention: if the programmer wants to fight himself, then he can, but this can have adverse side-effects on productivity...
- Most Java values are actually *references*. It is up to you to define whether a referenced object is part of what you consider to be "the instance contents". In your class, you have a field which references an (externally provided) array of integers. If the contents of that array are modified afterwards, would you consider that this breaks immutability of your `MyClass` instance ? There is no generic answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make an array immutable. That is there is no way to keep any client code from setting or removing or adding items to the array.

Here is a truly immutable alternative:

```
private static class MyClass
{
    private List<Integer> list;

    private MyClass(final int[] array)
    {
        final List<Integer> tmplist = new ArrayList<Integer>(array.length);
        for (int i : array)
        {
            tmplist.add(array[i]);
        }
        this.list = Collections.unmodifiableList(tmplist);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, both unmodifiableList and asList create views. Thus external changes to the array like in JaredPar's answer will cause changes in this version of MyClass.

Comment: `Arrays.asList(array)` will also return a `List<int[]>`.

Comment: who ever downvoted doesn't understand the immutable contract.
if you return a data structure that can be changed, regardless if it is a COPY of some backing array it is still __NOT__ immutable. Making a clone of something and returning a mutable clone does __NOT__ make a class 100% immutable, it also violates the principal of least astonishment. asList does __NOT__ create a "view" it creates a __MUTABLE__ copy of an array as a List. Unmodifiable is just that, it returns a list that is not modifiable, and thus immutable.

Comment: The lesson here is __NOT__ to use arrays and use an appropriate Collection class to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

To make a class immutable, you need to both ensure that all the fields on it are final, and that the types of those fields are immutable too.

This can be a pain to remember, but there is a tool to help you.

[Pure4J](https://github.com/robmoffat/pure4j) provides an annotation `@ImmutableValue`, which you can add to an interface or class.

There is a maven plugin to check at compile-time that you are meeting the rules on immutability following this.

Hope this helps.